# Access files using PHP and secured FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I need any site or book which teaches how to use ftp to access remote server in php.

Details of my problem:
Basically there are two servers.All user uploaded files are in server 2 but now I need to access those on my server1.

lets say my ftp details are like this:

```
ftp://userfiles.example.com
username: admin
password: 1234
```

then which php function can I use to create a connection to that server. I always accessed files like "../example/dir/example.txt", if there was no password then maybe I could do this 
"ftp://example.com/dir/example.txt".

Comment: FTP is a protocol for transfering files. I suppose you could, but I definitely do not recommend using PHP to login to a remote FTP server to access user uploaded files. That will definitely slow your site down. The overhead of running FTP to access remote data will be high. Second, why not copy the data from server2 to server1 and make it so that user uploaded files are, from now on, uploaded to server1? That definitely would be a more sane solution.

Comment: I hope i could. the company i m working with has actually employed me to do this work. their first warning was that we need a developer who can get us through this problem WITHOUT copying files files into server1. 
Many companies have different servers around the world, dont they use ftp. guide me if there is another better way than ftp.  :)

Comment: These are the only things I can think of at the moment: (1) If you use FTP, make the connection persistent. That way the handshake is done only when the server starts up. (2) Setup a NFS on server2; (3) make both servers web servers and serve the user uploaded files from there.

Comment: Also, "many companies have different servers around the world" --- true, but most of those servers are not logging into each other using FTP to send/receieve files. They use tools like chef and puppet to help manage them.

Comment: If you implement an FTP solution, you may want to use something other than the PHP FTP extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php). The PHP FTP extension does not support persistent connections (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9969). So...you could look for a library that already does this, or you could implement a persistent FTP connection in another language, then call it from PHP. Not ideal, but imo, it's better than not having a persistent connection. It all depends on how often the user uploaded files will be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

FTP and SFTP (you tagged your post with SFTP and kinda mention it in your question title) are different things. For FTP I'd recommend using [PHP's built-in FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php). For SFTP.. there's a PHP extension that provides for it ([ssh2](https://www.php.net/ssh2)) but, personally, I think [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), is easier to use.

If you're using FTPS (FTP over SSL) then use the FTP extension.

Comment: i will use either ftp or sftp after trying both and then deciding which one to use.
I know sftp and ftp are two different protocols.